# Serializer for class ... is not found. Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied

Tags: android, serialization, ktor, ktor-client

I am making an http request in my android application using Ktor framework. I am getting an error when I run the project.

Plugins:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.32"
}
```

Dependencies:

```
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-call-logging-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
```

Model Class:

```
@Serializable
data class GenreDto(
    @SerialName("data")
    val genreList: List<Genre>
)
```

API Calling:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
                install(ContentNegotiation) {
                    json(Json {
                        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                        prettyPrint = true
                        isLenient = true
                    })
                }
            }
            val response: GenreDto = client.get {
                url {
                    protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
                    url(BASE_URL)
                    path(GET_GENRE)
                }
            }.body()

            response.genreList.forEach { Log.e("Name", it.name) }
        }
```

I searched for a solution for hours. I followed many threads but none of them worked. I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: I am also used 'ignoreUnknownKeys = true'. However it doesn't work.

Comment: What version of `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` do you use?

Comment: I am currently using `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.21 apply false` @AlekseiTirman

Comment: Then please try to use the `plugin.serialization` plugin of the same version.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. .s

Comment: So do you get the same error?

Comment: I was getting serialization errors before. But I have no errors now. However it doesn't work.

Comment: What are expected and actual behaviors?

Comment: I expect to see my items on the home page. But I can't see any items on the page. And I have no errors in the logcat errors tab. :S